# Can I track which ads are in iFrames on my site and what users click in those iFrames without having to rely on ad network reporting?

Tags: advertising, iframe

As far as I am aware it is common for ad networks to displays advert in iframes.

To get statistics, how many views/clicks/conversions we rely in the ad network to be truthful/accurate.

Once I put an iframe on my site is it possible for my site to record how often an ad gets displayed, if a user clicked the ad and what URL they were taken to?

I have searched but suspect it is not possible due to forgery requests, XSS attacks etc. I hope that I can get a better understanding of this though.

Comment: Your last paragraph is confusing. Your second to last paragraph is perfectly clear if you just want to stick with that. This is really a coding question. The answer is likely Yes. However, it would be better to use a trustworthy partner. Much simpler that way.

Comment: See also on StackOverflow: [Track Google Adsense click with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952069/track-google-adsense-click-with-javascript)